# Using balanced multi-sets to estimate Chesbyschev's function $\psi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, estimation, chebyshev-function

I've found [this gem](http://emis.ams.org/journals/JIPAM/images/065_05_JIPAM/065_05.pdf) when I was looking for estimates on $\pi(x)$. In [the link](http://emis.ams.org/journals/JIPAM/images/065_05_JIPAM/065_05.pdf), the author proves that if you have a balanced multi-set (sum of the inverse of the terms is zero) and a few other conditions, then you get upper and lower bounds to $\psi(x)$. I don't completly understand it yet, but I want to know about ways to work with these bounds.

What I want to know is:

> 1) Is there a way to search these multi-sets in a way to get closer to 1?
>
> 2) What are the methods to find a $x_0$ from which the bounds are valid for all $x \ge x_0$?(Without getting into Dussart's inequalities and Rosser&Schoenfeld method's)